# Failed try to connecting metricbeat to elasticsearch and kibana with docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, metricbeat, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am trying to up elasticsearch kibana and metricbeat through docker-compose.

This is the [code](https://github.com/shashank1094/elkb-docker).

ELK is working fine but metricbeat failed, I am getting this error, and not able to figure out how can i solve this :

MetricBeat Log:

```
2020-05-09T19:27:03.353Z        ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://elasticsearch:9200)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: cannot retrieve the elasticsearch license from the /_xpack endpoint, Metricbeat requires the default distribution of Elasticsearch. Please make the endpoint accessible to Metricbeat so it can verify the license.: could not extract license information from the server response: unknown state, received: 'expired'
```

The license expired but i was hoping it would work without it.

Comment: `The license expired but i was hoping it would work without it.` :-) How useful would the license be ? [This](https://github.com/shashank1094/elkb-docker/blob/2a057bde6e1d10dadf9ad455f0a9b19faf4a5b19/README.md#how-to-disable-paid-features) explains how to proceed

Comment: again commenting for better reach and added docker tag as well.

Comment: @Val i did that, didn't work.